# Stylized HTML table with vertical scroll inside tbody

Tags: php, html, css

today I experimented with HTML tables and populating them from a MySQL database. My code worked well for what I needed and as is the table looked something like this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogYRwj

However I ran into a major problem when actually integrating it onto my website. I use the include statement to display my table as well as my menu to swap between all my webpages. The table was displayed like this:

[image: what the actual heck!?]

So I experimented with the width of the `tbody.td` element and I ended up changing this code:

```
thead th,tbody td {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

to this:

```
tbody td{
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

thead th {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

And somehow, it freakin' worked! But the lines between the `thead.th` elements didn't line up with the lines of the `tbody.td` elements on other devices such as my android, but it worked:

[image]

The code works when I include it using the PHP statement `include /path/to/file.php`, but now if I try to directly view /path/to/file.php it looks really strange, similar to the first image above!

Now I can't figure out what is wrong with the first version and how to display it properly on other devices such as Android?

Please come to rescue CSS and PHP wizards!

(**EDIT:**

---

- The HTML [output](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwWjax) is pretty much identical to the local except
  with results from the MySQL database.
- The table is put into a PHP file where I link to the CSS file using

> `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/style.css">`

- I have one main PHP file (index.php) in which I include the PHP file containing the HTML table (logs.php) using a function called getPage.

This is the code for index.php:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/functions/functions.php');

getPage('includes','home');
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fågelmatare</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Fågelmatare</h3>
        <hr />

        <a href="?page=home">Home</a> |
        <a href="?page=logs">Logs</a> |
        <a href="?page=videos">Videos</a> |
        <a href="?page=about">About</a>
        <hr />

        <?php
            if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
                getPage('includes','home');
            }else{
                getPage('includes',$_GET['page'], 'home');
            }
        //switch($_GET['page']{
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I click on the `<a href="?page=logs">Logs</a>` hyperlink to display my table (in logs.php).

In functions.php

```
<?php

function getPage($dir, $filename, $default = false){
    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path = $root . '/' . $dir;
    if(is_dir($path)){
        if(file_exists($path . '/' . $filename . '.php')){
            include $path . '/' . $filename . '.php';
            return true;
        }

        if(file_exists($path . '/' . $filename . '.html')){
            include $path . '/' . $filename . '.html';
            return true;
        }

        if($default){
            if(file_exists($path . '/' . $default . '.php')){
                include $path . '/' . $default . '.php';
                return true;
            }

            if(file_exists($path . '/' . $default . '.html')){
                include $path . '/' . $default . '.html';
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

Here is the source code for [logs.php](http://pastebin.com/Yd8vWcNk)

- I'm using nginx as my web server, running on a Raspberry Pi.

)

Comment: CSS and PHP are no wizardry :) what does your outputted HTML look like ? Does it perfectly match what you have in your example ? How are the styles applied ? In what php file do you include another one ? Give us some overview of your setup

Comment: @sodawillow Right, I've updated my question. Hopefully it should be much more clear now!

Comment: @Linus, if the second image is how you want your table to look, get rid of the 'float'. Tables act strangely with positioning CSS.

Comment: @thePav Do you mean the `float:left` in the `tbody td, thead th {` block? If so what should I use instaed?

Comment: @Linus, yes the float:left, you don't need float left in table td (or even th) as they are automatically aligned next to each other within the tr.

Comment: @thePav Commenting out `float:left` gives this result: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myRwvz

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach, although cross browser support still isn't very good. It uses position:sticky so you'll need to test in Safari or enable experimental flags for position:sticky.

Here's the experiment:
http://codepen.io/jpdevries/pen/vLVbpQ?editors=1100

The idea is that you wrap the `<table>` in a `<div>`, set that `<div>` to `position:relative` then simply set the `<thead>` to `position:sticky;top:0;`.

You can then just set the `max-height` and `overflow` on the wrapper `<div>` to make that scrollable. As it scrolls, the `<thead>` will stick to the top.

It is admittedly sort of a "cheap trick" because as you can see below the scrollbar starts at the top of the `<table>`, not the top of the `<tbody>`. It is quick and easy though and should be more relevant once browser support stabilizes.

[image: screenshot of table with sticky thead and scrollbars]

Comment: I just learned there is a known issue where this trick doesn't work in Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=975644